# Gradle Multiproject: Subproject fails when linked to parent

Tags: java, gradle, configuration

I have the current following project: https://github.com/javydreamercsw/pcgen.git on the Network-Enhancements branch if someone wants to look at the actual project.

Compiling the root project works fine, but I'm trying to run the subproject on it's own and has the following failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/javier/NetBeans_Projects/pcgen/build.gradle' line: 183

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'pcgen'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [{group=org.jetbrains, name=annotations, version=15.0}] on root project 'pcgen'.
```

The mentioned line is a comile dependency on the root project which doesn't make sense to me.

If I remove the sub project from the root, it compiles and runs perfectly. I'm new to Gradle so I'm sure is a dumb mistake somewhere.

On the root project build.gradle it is added as follows:

```
dependecies {
  ...
  compile project(':PCGenServer')
}
```

And on the root settings.gradle is added as follows:

```
include ':PCGenServer'
```

Any idea?

Comment: If the 'PCGenServer' is a subproject of 'pcgen', then wouldn't it mean that `compile project(':PCGenServer')` is declaring a dependency on itself?

Comment: PCGenServer is a subproject of pcgen. The pieces of the gradle files specify "on the root"

Comment: All right, I've checked out your branch and built the project. I've encountered no problems.

Comment: It compiles fine, but if you try to run the subproject directly it causes errors.